# C# MySQL Read must be called first

Tags: c#, .net-core, mysqlconnector

Есть странная проблема.
Вот код:

```
string[] ret = new string[3];
string SQLTablename = configdata(Config)["SQL"]["UserTable"];
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(SQLConnSTR);
connect.Open();
string sqlcmd = String.Format("SELECT * FROM `{0}` WHERE `ID` = {1}", SQLTablename, ID);
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlcmd, connect);
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
ret[0] = reader["ID"].ToString();
ret[1] = reader["Name"].ToString();
ret[2] = reader["SelectedMember"].ToString();
reader.Close();
connect.Close();
return ret;
```

Он работает нормально при запуске отладки, но стоит мне собрать проект (проект netcore), то вываливается ошибка

```
16-12-2020 20:37:15 : Read must be called first.
16-12-2020 20:37:16 :    at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.GetCurrentRow() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 420
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.get_Item(String name) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 196
   at ПУТЬДОФАЙЛА.getuserinfo(String Config, UInt64 ID)
```

*Ошибка появляется при попытке выполнить этот код*

*`ПУТЬДОФАЙЛА` это путь до функции. Я просто его скрыл*

Comment: Это где у вас в коде такое имя `ПУТЬДОФАЙЛА`?

Comment: @Bulson Это я скрыл путь до функции в проекте

Comment: Надо код, который работает с БД или с файловой системой или с сетью обязательно оборачивать в `try/catch` и в блоке `catch` записывать в лог с помощью хотя бы `Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);`  в текстовой файл сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: @Bulson Это я и так сделал. Ошибка ниже взята из `ex.Message` и `ex.StackTrace`.

Comment: Вот про это пишут что-то, но я не понял, что делать https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/379

Comment: Лучше писать в таком духе [https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/blob/0568e6e0b01810204775434d5a6d0bef00186688/WinFormsMySql/WinFormsMySql/Services/MySqlRepository.cs#L26]

Comment: @Bulson Я не знаю что это было. Но через некоторое время ошибка исчезла. Код я не менял O_o
Но всё же интересно почему возникала ошибка того, что `reader` не был вызван первым, хотя он вызывается верно.

Comment: Исчезающая/появляющаяся ошибка это не есть гуд. Попробуйте работать с БД в асинхронном стиле, ссылку я дал выше.

Comment: @Bulson Спасибо за линк) 
Что касается ошибки, то в таком виде много чего написано внутри проекта и оно работает уже примерно год. (Это проект бота). Такую ошибку я встретил впервые.

Comment: Крч я окончательно понял в чём была ошибка.
Ошибка в том, что БД по запросу возвращала `null` ибо по условию не подходила ни одна запись. Ошибка `Read must be called first` была из за того, что я пытался прочесть `reader` в котором ничего не было.

Comment: Ошибка означает, что не был вызван метод `reader.Read();`. Это значит, что либо вы компилировали другой код, либо в коде была ошибка, он не компилировался, а запускался предыдущий, в котором не был вызван этот метод. Смотрите в системе контроля версий, какой код был до этого.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я уже комментарием выше расписал причину проблемы)

Comment: OK, дополню. Вы не написали решение проблемы. Нужно обязательно добавить проверку: `if (reader.Read()) { // здесь получаем данные из ридера }`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я как раз хотел это расписать, но позже) Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что БД по запросу возвращала `null` ибо по условию не подходила ни одна запись. Ошибка `Read must be called first` была из за того, что я пытался прочесть `reader` в котором ничего не было.
Этого можно избежать добавив проверку `if (reader.Read())`. В итоге код будет выглядеть так

```
string[] ret = new string[3];
string SQLTablename = configdata(Config)["SQL"]["UserTable"];
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(SQLConnSTR);
connect.Open();
string sqlcmd = String.Format("SELECT * FROM `{0}` WHERE `ID` = {1}", SQLTablename, ID);
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlcmd, connect);
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read()){
    // Получаем данные из reader
    ret[0] = reader["ID"].ToString();
    ret[1] = reader["Name"].ToString();
    ret[2] = reader["SelectedMember"].ToString();
    reader.Close();
    connect.Close();
    return ret;
} 
else {
    // Если reader оказался пустой
    return null;
}
```